# ListView with 3 columns

Tags: android

I have a listView with checkbox which populate from sqlite table.
I need to have another column in listView that shows another sqlite table column.

I'd like to show 3 columns:

```
ProductName CheckBox ProductPrice.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about listview from http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive

Comment: Thanks,But i'm not able to populate custom list view from database. I can show the column with productName and the column with checbox, and it works fine. But i don't know how to show the third column.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom list adapter for the purpose.

http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/

use SimpleCursorAdapter to bind data with Cursor columns:

Lets Assume you have a row layout defined into row_layout.xml, having three textviews textview1, textview2, textview3, which needed to be binded with COLUMN_NAME1, COLUMN_NAME2, COLUMN_NAME3,

S

```
impleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, // Use a template
                                          // that displays a
                                          // text view
    cur, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
    new String[] {COLUMN.NAME1, COLUMN.NAME2. COLUMN.NAME3}, // Map the NAME column in the
                                         // people database to...
    new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
```

Comment: Thanks,But i don't know how to bind the custom list with sqlite database.